# Cannot convert MP3 to wav to burn audio CD

Tags: windows-10, mp3, wav, audio-conversion, audio-cd

I have made a mp3 recording using Perfect recorder app on Windows 8 Phone Lumia 635. I have transfered this 2 mp3 files to a Windows 10 PC. I can play this files without any problem in Windows media player or the new metro style player.

But when I try to burn it as audio CD with the media player it throws an error (there is a red cross indicating some unspecified problem). When I try to convert it with the VLC media player, it produces a playable but a very noisy poor quality wav file.

Other mp3 to wav cobnverters, like Freac or Free online mp3 to wav converter, fail completely producing almost empty file. There is probably some problem  with file headers, I have tried a software that should fix mp3 but no success.

Is there any other way how to convert or burn audio cd from playable but somehow corrupted mp3?

Comment: have you tried FFMPEG (WinFF if you want a neat GUI)...? The multimedia Swiss army knife!

Comment: Thanks @BigChris, this software is small and easy to use, it converted the problematic MP3 to wav without any problem.

Answer (score -1):

**Update**. Getting `Super` from sourceforge without virus warnings seems to be a problem. Recently I found [Handbrake](https://handbrake.fr/), which offers lot of the functionalities without the tricky website, so I update my recommendation to use this one instead.

---

*It might be a hassle to navigate the website, but I'd recommend converting your audio files using [Super](http://www.erightsoft.com/SUPER.html).
Open the page, go to the bottom and click on "Start downloading Super"
[image]
Then search on the next page for "download Super setup file..."
[image]
Once you install it, you open the program, drag your mp3 files to its window and select the output audio file as the desired WAV. You can let the default values for bitrate and so on. It can convert almost any format, includes all codecs on its own and works really well.*

Comment: I strongly discourage anyone from downloading this program. It is overfilled with bloatware, even after unchecking each box during the installation (and there were like 7 of them), I got some system scanner installed on C:\. And now after installation I get Trojan notification from my Kaspersky.